# Bash: Starting each line of a command output with a comment symbol

Tags: bash, comments, substitution

I have a command that outputs three lines like this:

```
L1
L2
L3
```

I need to append each of those lines into a data file for Gnuplot, where there is no "comment block", and thus you can only prepend the "#" symbol to each line. I'm scripting this whole process in bash, how do I substitute a `\n` for `\n#` in bash?

Comment: The answers to this question might help you: http://serverfault.com/questions/72744/command-to-prepend-string-to-each-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and pipe your command through sed like this:

```
command | sed -e "s/^/#/"
```

It will replace the first character of first line with # followed by said character.

If you also want to get stderr, then throw stderr into stdout first like this:

```
command 2>&1 | sed -e "s/^/#/"
```

EDIT: thanks @ДМИТРИЙ МАЛИКОВ ! I just leadend something new. I've updated my blocks with your even shorter expression

Comment: Why not simply match `/^/`?

Comment: I ended up using `cmd | awk '{print "#, from " $0}'`, but yours works as well.